# Using Instrumentation to record unhandled exception

Tags: java, aspectj, instrumentation, javaagents

I was trying to debug java application using instrumentation. The problem with current system are

- Hardly written any log statements
- Poor exception handling

This made very difficult to trace root cause of broken functionality.

To handle the situation I have developed tool,java agent using `Instrumentation` API , and I was able to inject log statements and half of the problem solved.

But the next problem is to recording the Exception. I want to extend my tool record every exception thrown during the execution of the application.  I tried injecting 'try-catch' block using `javaassist` API for methods (using `addCatch`, `insertBefore` and `insertAfter`), and it is effective certain extent.

```
public byte[] transform(ClassLoader    loader,
        String              className,
        Class<?>            classBeingRedefined,
        ProtectionDomain    protectionDomain,
        byte[]              classfileBuffer)
        throws IllegalClassFormatException {
     if (className.startsWith("com/alu/")) {
          return insertLog(className, classBeingRedefined, classfileBuffer);
     }

     if(className.endsWith("Exception")){
         System.out.println("============= exception occured "+className);
     }
```

Here  `inserLog(..)` method will inject necessary log statement and works fine,but when there is any Exception it doesn't come to transformer.

But the problem is some of the method handles exception inside ( even with out log/sysout).

eg:

```
try {
            if(search.equals("Category")){
                //do operation
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

This code eats `NullPointerException` when value of `search` is null, I never know this exception and application fail for some thing else.

Ultimately what I want is a mechanism to record any exception thrown by application.  following details  are to be captured

- Exception Type
- Excpetion Stacktrace
- Method and class name

I know there is API `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`, but not sure how it use with java instrumentation. I don't have any source access the application.

**[update 1]**

I found below link tells to use `retransformation` , I will give a try and update

[How to instrument java system classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302862/how-to-instrument-java-system-classes?rq=1)

Any guidance would be greatly helpful.

Comment: > but when there is any Exception it doesn't come to transformer.

Please, clarify this statement. How do you know that Exception does not come to transformer? Do you wait for `============= exception occured` in stdout? Of course, it won't, because you instrumenting you code, that throws exception, and you log all exceptions being retransformed itself.

Comment: @AlexeyAndreev, I am not quite clear with the statement  `you log all exceptions being retransformed itself` , could you rephrase it pls

Comment: OK, I will extend my answer, as it is not so easy to write complex comments here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should use ASM to manipulate bytecode directly. Here is algoritms:

1. Visit all try/catch blocks (see [visitTryCatchBlock](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitTryCatchBlock%28org.objectweb.asm.Label,%20org.objectweb.asm.Label,%20org.objectweb.asm.Label,%20java.lang.String%29)) and save all `handler` labels
2. Visit instructions until one of the `handler` labels met.
3. After `handler` label insert logging code

   ```
   GETSTATIC java/lang/System out
   LDC "exception X occured"
   INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream println (java/lang/String)V
   ```

And ensure that your javaagent works fine. Checkt that your MANIFEST.MF file contains proper `premain` declaration and enables class transformation.

---

About your current code. Here

```
 if (className.startsWith("com/alu/")) {
      return insertLog(className, classBeingRedefined, classfileBuffer);
 }
```

you transforming classes inside particular package. That classes contain code that, in particular, throw exceptions.

And here

```
 if(className.endsWith("Exception")){
     System.out.println("============= exception occured "+className);
 }
```

you log of class being retransfomed when it is first loaded by JVM, when its name ends with `"Exception"`. Not when exception occured. But transforming exception is useless itself. So I guess you should proceed like this:

```
if (className.startsWith("com/alu/")) {
    System.out.println("============= class transformed "+ className);
    return insertLog(className, classBeingRedefined, classfileBuffer);
}
```

So you could know that your agent at least works.

---

You have to deal with code like this

```
    try {
        if(search.equals("Category")){
            //do operation
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

where exceptions are swallowed. You transform methods that they will be like this:

```
try {
    try {
        if(search.equals("Category")){
            //do operation
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Of course, when exception was swallowed by the first `catch`, the second one never cathes it. Instead, you should transform existing `catch` blocks themself, to get the following code:

```
try {
    if(search.equals("Category")){
        //do operation
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Above I shown you how to achieve this with ASM.

Comment: hmmm, I got your point, I need to visit all catch block and the transform it. Good idea! thanks man

Comment: thanks for directions. I am able to record the exception with Instrumentation. Later I will look in to asm to fine tune my solution. Posted my solution below.

Comment: I understand modifying System classes(adding new field/method) is some thing not possible with `javaassist` , hence I vote for your solution.

Answer (score 3):

After more research, I found a starting point(thanks to @jarnbjo), which I believe take me to complete solution

There is an option to retransform `System` classes,

```
SimpleClassTransformer transformer = new SimpleClassTransformer();
    instrumentation.addTransformer(transformer,true);
    try {
        instrumentation.retransformClasses(java.lang.NullPointerException.class);
    } catch (UnmodifiableClassException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I applied this code in my `premain` class and able to reload the NullPointerException class. I still would need to work on `Transformer` implementation to enable instant recording of exception.

**[update 2]**  **Finally I got a break through!!**

After re transforming the required Exception class, I injected my code right inside the constructor of the `Exception` class.

Here is my transformer class,

public class SimpleClassTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer{

```
public byte[] transform(ClassLoader    loader,
        String              className,
        Class<?>            classBeingRedefined,
        ProtectionDomain    protectionDomain,
        byte[]              classfileBuffer)
                throws IllegalClassFormatException {
    System.out.println("----------------- "+className);
    if (className.startsWith("com/alu/")) {
        return insertLog(className, classBeingRedefined, classfileBuffer);
    }

    if(className.endsWith("Exception")){
        System.out.println("============= exception occured");
        return recordError(className, classBeingRedefined, classfileBuffer);
    }

    return classfileBuffer;
}

private byte[] recordError(String name, Class clazz, byte[] b){
    ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    CtClass cl = null;
    try {
        cl = pool.makeClass(new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(b));
        if (cl.isInterface() == false) {
            CtConstructor[] constr=cl.getDeclaredConstructors();
            for(CtConstructor con:constr){
                    con.insertAfter("System.out.println(\"Hey hurrray I got you mannnnnnn  -------\");  ");
            }
            b = cl.toBytecode();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        if (cl != null) {
            cl.detach();
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: I have got an exception "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: retransformClasses is not supported in this environment" when retransformClasses.

Comment: For anyone using this approach: Make sure you have the line `Can-Retransform-Classes: true` in your `MANIFEST.MF` of your agent-jar

Answer (score 1):

I solved this challenge this way. I used **javaassist** method `addCatch`.

Short demo

```
 CtClass exceptionCtClass = ClassPool.getDefault().makeClass("java.lang.Exception");
 method.addCatch("{ System.out.println(\"Caught exception\");\n$_e.printStackTrace();\nthrow $_e; }", exceptionCtClass, "$_e");
```

Full example

```
public class ExceptionReporterAgent {

    public static void premain(final String agentArgs, final Instrumentation inst) {
        inst.addTransformer(new ExceptionReporterTransformer());
    }
}

public class ExceptionReporterTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer {

    private CtClass exceptionCtClass;

    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class redefiningClass, ProtectionDomain domain, byte[] bytes) {
        return transformClass(redefiningClass, bytes);
    }

    private byte[] transformClass(Class classToTransform, byte[] b) {
        ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        CtClass cl = null;
        try {
            cl = pool.makeClass(new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(b));
            if (cl.getName().endsWith("ClassCException")) {
                exceptionCtClass = cl; //Or any exception, you can move this logic into constructor.
            } else {
                modifyClass(cl);
            }

            b = cl.toBytecode();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (cl != null) {
                cl.detach();
            }
        }

        return b;
    }

    private byte[] modifyClass(CtClass cl) throws Exception {
        CtBehavior[] methods = cl.getDeclaredBehaviors();
        for (CtBehavior method : methods) {
            changeMethod(method);
        }
        return cl.toBytecode();
    }

    private void changeMethod(CtBehavior method) throws CannotCompileException {
        method.addLocalVariable("$_start", CtClass.longType);
        method.addLocalVariable("$_end", CtClass.longType);
        method.addLocalVariable("$_total", CtClass.longType);
        method.insertBefore("{ $_start = System.currentTimeMillis(); }");

        //For methods returning String
        // method.insertAfter("{ $_end = System.currentTimeMillis();\n$_total = $_end - $_start;\nSystem.out.println(\"Total: \" + $_total);return \"AAA\"; }");


        method.addCatch("{ System.out.println(\"Caught exception\");\n$_e.printStackTrace();\nthrow $_e; }", exceptionCtClass, "$_e");

        //For methods returning String
        // method.insertAfter("{ System.out.println(\"Finally\");\nreturn \"ABC\"; }", true);

        method.insertBefore("{ System.out.println(\"Before\"); }");

        System.out.println("Modifying method: " + method.getName());
    }
}
```