# Java Exception Listener

Tags: java, exception, listener

Is there a way to listen any exceptions in java?

My purpose is creating a library that listens & collects all rised errors in java. Are there any way to do this?

Comment: No, there isn't an exception listener. You hava to write your own code in everhy try-catch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can catch every uncaught exception via [Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html). If that's not sufficient I would perhaps suggest some [AOP/bytecode-weaving solution](http://www.coderanch.com/t/561286/aop/AspectJ-catch-handle-exception-aspectJ) to implement some watch around each created exception.

Answer (score 2):

I have done some thing similar using `Java instrumentation API`, Create java agent and Class transformer to catch hold of required Exception class and instrument the byte code as necessary

you can follow up here
[Using Instrumentation to record unhandled exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282619/using-instrumentation-to-record-unhandled-exception)

Above links will give you idea of how/when to use ASM or Instrumentation