# Is there a way to listen all exceptions?

Tags: java, exception, exceptionhandler

My purpose is creating a Java library which listens and store all errors. I have caught every uncaught exception via [`Thread#UncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html), 
but when Java code has `try` and `catch` block inside the code and is not throwing exception explicitly at that time above `UncaughtExceptionHandler` will not work.

Ultimately what I want is a mechanism to record all caught and uncaught exceptions.

Comment: what is the goal of doing such a process?

Comment: You'd need to do that at the JVM level (not in application code). Do you have a platform with DTrace? Otherwise probably only possible via the debugger API.

Comment: An exception within a `try-catch` is not uncaught...it's caught, that's the point...

Comment: Here is someone doing this via bytecode instrumentation (-javaagent): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282619/using-instrumentation-to-record-unhandled-exception

Comment: @KickButtowski If I had to guess, probably an application whose functions are used by non-technical people whose talents don't lie in bug reporting. I know I've wanted to get all exception data, so I had something to work with other than "it just crashed," but I can't imagine catching every exception encountered by the application is the best option.

Comment: try{
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStrackTree();
}

Comment: @furkle thank you so much for your explanation, but the op had to be more clear which it was not

Comment: @furkle - *" ... but I can't imagine catching every exception encountered by the application is the best option."* - That is an understatement!  The chances are that many / most of those handled exceptions are not errors at all.  If the OP has concerns about poor error reporting (or exception squashing) then using a source code analyser is a better option.