# How to monitor for Java Exceptions externally?

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to implement a real time metrics system which monitors java applications running in a docker environment. I have a spring boot web application which works as the external client that polls spring boot actuator endpoints of each of the applications in the docker environment to return metrics which are then sent to the front end in real time via websockets, which works nicely.

My next feature is to implement an "exception history" to monitor exceptions thrown by any of the docker environment applications including the class, method and type of the exception and send that data over the websocket.

Ideally I want to have little to no configuration of the applications being monitored and want to collect all this exception data externally either via REST or by another means, as long as it can monitor logs/exceptions of the docker applications in the environment. This is due to the fact that it defeats the purpose if you have to configure every application you add to be monitored and I want it to work in such a way that you can just run the data collection client and it will start monitoring all the docker apps on a certain host for metrics/exceptions.

Is this feasible? Is there any open source java exception logging APIs that I could use to collect this data? Hope the question makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: So, you're looking to do a Syslog-style logger only when you receive exceptions?

Comment: Yeah thats right, when an exception is thrown/detected in any of the docker apps, I'd like data about that exception to be transmitted over the websocket and displayed in the front end.

Comment: i would find a way to instrument each app. i think they can observe for exceptions. if coded well should have little impact on performance. can look t java agents and pre main

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282619/using-instrumentation-to-record-unhandled-exception not as easy as u want - needs a generic code to be copied and hooked into the app/ container (like tomcat or other container/ main class to JVM level) to work