# Collection Instrumentation from java agent

Tags: java, collections, instrumentation

Is there any limitation in java for collection instrumentation? My custom classes are get instrumented from my java agent, but collection classes stay the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3768057/1817029

Comment: it's not related. that topic is about collection size and about instrumentation

Comment: looks like the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302862/how-to-instrument-java-system-classes